# Google has all the wrong keywords

Tags: seo, keyword

I hope stackoverflow is the right part of the trinity to ask this kind of question ...

Google webmaster tools shows the keywords it considers important for my blog (blog.schauderhaft.de). But among the top 20% are all the month names (you know january and so on).

I actually have a two part question about this:

- why does google think theses are important keywords?
- how do I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might have something to do with the whole list of archives in the head of your page: `<link rel='archives' title='January 2008'` and so on.

Do you think this will actually be a problem? [These people](http://www.webmasterworld.com/google/3633699.htm) don't seem to think so..

Comment: /palm head/ ok that explains where it is coming from. Google says that the keywords should match the subject matter of the site, so therefore I am afraid it might matter.

Comment: Makes me wonder if there is a WP plugin to create more meaningful names for archives ... Something containing the tags

Comment: Well, maybe, but the archives are based on months not on tags. It might be a good idea to build the archive on tags, but a tag is still only a single keyword that will probably hardly describe the content of a blog post. Besides, the Google indexing is very smart and content focused, and it has many ways to weigh the importance of a page and the relevancy of a keyword. I wouldn't worry too much about these month names unless you got a reason to. Do you think they actually make your blog less findable? And if so, why do you think that?

Comment: Other than the advice on the google page: no. My site seems pretty 'findable' to me, and I don't get tons of people looking for october either.

Answer (score 0):

We used to have a big problem on one of our client websites with a similar problem country names appearing most important. On some pages we were running multiple forms where one could choose a country. Google was finding this all over the place and thus considered it important.

So if you have month names in archives/in dates of articles it might very well be a possibility. You have to ensure you tag each one properly if its a date you can maybe use the HTML5 code to identify that its a date; otherwise in case of archives what you can do is load this using AJAX; or calculate it using javascript.

In order to drop the counry names we had to use a jQuery trick to insert these dynamically into the page following page load. (so google no longer sees the list as important to our website)